# Compute the camera center of the camera and the principal axis

Tags: coordinate-systems, projective-geometry, computer-vision

The subject is **Pinhole Camera**.

I've given a camera matrix $P =  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$  and these $3D$ points: $X_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    2  \\
   3 \\
    1
    \end{pmatrix}, X_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    1  \\
   1 \\
    1
    \end{pmatrix}, X_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    1  \\
   -1 \\
    1
    \end{pmatrix}$

I need to compute it's position (camera center) and its principal axis (viewing direction). I haven't found anything on how to compute the position and viewing direction, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The camera center is a null vector for the camera matrix.

Comment: @littleO I see, so it's easily computed with $Px=0$, how about the viewing direction? Thank you.

Comment: The three points really don’t have anything to do with the anatomy of the camera matrix. See Table 6.1 of Hartley & Zisserman’s _Multiple View Geometry In Computer Vision_ or similar sources for a complete geometric breakdown of the camera matrix.

Comment: @amd You're right, I wasn't entirely sure about that so I decided to add it anyways. Thanks!

Comment: @amd I'll take a look at the book right away, thanks!

Comment: A way to find the viewing direction is to compute the camera’s principal plane, which passes through the center and is parallel to the image plane. This plane gets mapped to the line at infinity. That leaves a sign ambiguity if you want the “forward” direction.

Comment: @amd I posted some [Multiple View Geometry code](https://github.com/danielvoconnor/MultipleViewGeometry) on Github not long ago. On the off chance that you're ever in the mood to look at it, please feel free to let me know if you have any suggestions about how to improve it. (It's difficult to get expert feedback on this type of thing.)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in one of the comments, the camera centre is the right null vector of the camera matrix, in other words it is the only point for which the image $P\textbf{C}$ is not defined.

If we write the camera matrix $P$ as $[M | \textbf{p}^4]$, then the (inhomogeneous) direction of the principal axis toward the front of the camera is given by det$(M)\textbf{m}^3$ where $\textbf{m}^3$ is the last row of $M$. This is because the third row of $P$ represents the principal plane of the camera and the first three coordinates together i.e. $\textbf{m}^3$ represent the direction of the normal to the principal plane (the principal axis direction).

So in this case the inhomogeneous coordinates of the camera centre are $(0, 0, -1)^T$ and principal axis is along the positive $z$ direction, $(0, 0, 1)^T$.